# ora-28040 no matching authentication protocol

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

I am getting error that say

> ora-28040 no matching authentication protocol

when trying to connect `Oracle Forms 6i` with `ORacle database 12c`

I searched and found that this issue is because of connection restriction 
that oracle 12c has while oracle Forms 6i do not

I know oracle forms 6i are really old but this is business requirements so 
I have nothing to do with upgrading current software ...etc etc

So please if there is any work around for this

Comment: The hits on Google for this error all see to be for JDBC drivers, but I guess it's generic for other drivers too. Have you tried the suggested workaround, setting the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` parameter to =`7` (on both client and server)?  [Find out more](http://www.redstk.com/ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol-after-upgrade-to-12c/)

Comment: @APC forms run time still not working while developer connect but when trying to compile `FMB` I got error message that say internal error

Answer (score 0):

`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` is deprecated since 12c you need to add

`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8`
and

`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8`

to your sqlnet.ora, and reload the listener after you update the file